# Refresh the ClientFooterTemplate of Kendo UI MVC grid on edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use the Kendo UI grid in ajax mode and have a ClientFooterTemplate with a sum of the total for a column. This all works well, but if I create/update or remove a record the ClientFooterTemplate is not updated and the sum value stays the same.

How can I update the ClientFooterTemplate so that the sum value is up to date after create/update or delete?

This is what I tried so far:

```
.Events(events =>
{
    events.SaveChanges("SaveChanges");
    events.Remove("Remove");
    events.Save("SaveChanges");
})
<script>
    function SaveChanges(e) {
        Reload(e.sender);
    }
    function Remove(e) {
        Reload(e.sender);
    }
    function Reload(obj) {
        obj.dataSource.read();
    }
</script>
```

The obj.dataSource.read() is executed before the actual request to update.

Comment: Idk the difference between save and save changes but maybe those 2 events are clashing. Try removing as many variables as you can. So instead of calling Reload after SaveChanges, just do a read. Maybe try a different event close or change maybe

Answer (score 2):

you need to update the `datasource` and fetch again if you using aggregates sum in you gird footer the following JavaScript will update your footer sum every time you create/update any row.

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
  .Ajax()
  .Aggregates(aggregates =>
  {
    aggregates.Add(p => p.WorkOrderDetailsQuantity).Sum();
    aggregates.Add(p => p.Total).Sum();                         
  })
.Events(e=>e.Edit("onEdit").Save("onSave"))

function onSave(e)
{
  //update the aggregate columns
  var dataSource = this.dataSource;
  e.model.one("change", function () {
    dataSource.one("change", function () {
      dataSource.aggregates().Total.sum;
    });
    dataSource.fetch();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to do a refresh on the grid's data source.
So after the update you can refresh it like this...

```
 var grid = $("#ProposalGrid").data("kendoGrid");
             grid.dataSource.page(1) // or
             grid.dataSource.read() //if dataSource Read expects a paramater
             grid.dataSource.read( {paramNameAsDefinedInController : value });
```

Comment: I did try this, but the Save event is executed before the actual request to save. This is what I tried:

     .Events(events =>
     {
      events.SaveChanges("SaveChanges");
      events.Remove("Remove");
      events.Save("SaveChanges");
     })

<script>
 function SaveChanges(e) {
  Reload(e.sender);
 }
 function Remove(e) {
  Reload(e.sender);
 }
 function Reload(obj) {
  obj.dataSource.read();
 }
</script>

It first does the read() and then the actual request to save.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reload your data, you can always do something like this (a little hacky...):

First, use a different function for the Save event vs. the SaveChanges event, e.g.:

```
.Events(events => {
    events.Save("Save");
    events.SaveChanges("SaveChanges");
    events.Remove("Remove")
})
```

Second, define the JavaScript method, e.g.:

```
function Save(e) {
    if (e.value.Gewgaw) { // replace 'Gewgaw' with your column name
        var footer = $('tr.k-footer-template'),
            idx = 3, // replace 3 with the column index you want to aggregate
            aggregate = $(footer).children('td')[idx]; 

        // I had to delay the stuff in this function to get it to load properly
        setTimeout(function () { 
            var sum = 0;

            $('tr[role=row][data-uid]').each(function(i, e) {
                var $cell = $($(e).children()[idx]);

                /* do any necessary manipulations before this 
                   if your cell is formatted */
                var cellAmount = parseFloat($cell.text()); 

                sum += cellAmount;
            });

            /* do any necessary formatting to sum before this 
               if your cell is formatted */
            $(aggregate).text(sum); 
        }, 50); 
    }
}
```

If you do that stuff and remove/add the appropriate formatting, it should update the aggregate each time the respective cell is edited.